# Associativity in the fundamental groupoid of a space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the set of all path homotopy classes of paths in $X$  with $[f]\cdot[g]=[f*g]$ defining a binary operation. We have a groupoid with the following conditions:

1) $[c_p][f]=[f]=[f][c_q]$ where $p=f(0)$, $q=f(1)$ and $[c_r]$ denotes a path constant at $r$.

2) $([f]\cdot[g])\cdot[h] =[f]( [g][h])$ where  $f(1)=g(0)$ and $g(1)=h(0)$

3) every path has an inverse.

How can I prove condition 2 (associativity of groupoid) by use of positive linear maps? this proof is in Munkres book but I don't understand it.

Comment: It's going to be hard to give a better proof than a textbook. The advantage of a site like this is that you can precisely describe at which point you are stuck and what confuses you. Please do so.

Comment: please check my edit.

Comment: Why We use of positive linear map ? Indeed What work do this linear maps for us to prooving the associativity property?

Comment: Can you prove (1)? This also uses certain linear maps.

Comment: To prove (1) : Let C be the constant path at 0 and i be the identity path (i(t)=t)  @@@ C(1)=0=i(0) so C*i from I to I be a path and i so .I is contractible so c*i is homotopic to i .hence $f$ o ( c*i) is homotopic to $f_0$ (i) = c(2t) if 0<t<1/2 and i(2t-1)=2t-1 for 1/2<t<1 .that is equal to f(0)=p=c_p(2t) where 0<t<1/2 and f(2t-1) where 1/2<t<1  that equal to c_p *f (t) and so we have fo(i)=f so c_p*f is homotopic to f so the (1) is proved .

Comment: see the https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7Z2gvey4ZR5S0VxSmtyU1l2Mm8/edit?usp=drive_web&urp=http://www.google.com/url?sa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3Dtopology%2520     page 328 the fundamental group

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/80369

Comment: If you use paths as maps $f:[0,r]\to X$ where $r \geqslant 0$ then composition of paths is strictly associative and has strict identities, i.e. forms a category. See the book "Topology and Groupoids" (first edition, 1968).